# Check if no array elements fulfill a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to perform an action in JavaScript code only if no array elements fulfill a condition. What's the optimal way to do it?

In this particular case, I need to push something to the dataLayer only if it's not already present. Here's what I did:

```
if (!window.dataLayer.some(
     (element) => element.event === 'some_label',
   )) {
    gtm.push(someTrackingObject);
   }
```

Is there a better / more concise way?

Comment: Seems like a pretty good way to me? What could be better?

Comment: What you did already is a good way to do it you can use `.every`. 

If you have a lot of data you can use a map or set to be more efficient when it comes to lookup time. But this only makes sense when you have multiple lookups and a large array size.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I was thinking if the negation of `some` with an equality condition is better than `every` with an inequality condition... Or if there is maybe a third solution, with some iteration, mapping, something like that. No idea :)

Comment: @VincentMenzel in this case, the array has around 20 elements, so the performance is not a big issue

Comment: In that case i would recommend to use @Magnus Enebakk solution. In my optionin ever is more easily readable than !some. I will also include a `.find` way in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.every()`

If you want to check if no elements fulfull one specific condition, just inverse the condition

```js
datalayer.every((element) => element.event !== "some_label")

> true // if no elements has "some_label"
> false // if some element has "some_label"
```

Using `.some()` is good enough, so `.every()` is just an alternative way.

Comment: Yup, I was thinking whether to use `every` with an inequality condition, or `some` with an equality condition and a negation in front of it...

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach using Array.prototype.some() is optimal for checking if no array elements fulfill a condition, as it stops iterating over the array as soon as the condition is met, avoiding unnecessary iterations.

```
if (!window.dataLayer.some((element) => element.event === 'some_label')) {
    gtm.push(someTrackingObject);
}
```

However, if you want a more concise version, you can use the Array.prototype.indexOf() method to achieve the same result:

```
if (window.dataLayer.indexOf(someTrackingObject) === -1) {
    gtm.push(someTrackingObject);
}
```

Here, **Array.prototype.indexOf()** returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present. Note that this approach assumes that **someTrackingObject** is unique in the **window.dataLayer** array.

Both approaches have their pros and cons:

- **Array.prototype.some():**

  - Pros:

    - Stops iterating over the array as soon as the condition is met, making it more efficient in cases where the element is found early in the array.
  - Cons:

    - Less concise than **Array.prototype.indexOf()**
- **Array.prototype.indexOf():**

  - Pros:

    - More concise than Array.prototype.some().
  - Cons:

    - Does not stop iterating over the array, which may be less efficient if the element is found late in the array.

In summary, your current approach using **Array.prototype.some()** is optimal for checking if no array elements fulfill a condition, and you can consider using **Array.prototype.indexOf()** for a more concise version if **someTrackingObject** is unique in the **window.dataLayer** array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, I want to avoid adding duplicate objects to the dataLayer, so in theory there  should never be two `someTrackingObject`s at the time when this check is performed. I just opted to check the label instead of the whole object, since I know that I should have only one object with a given label.

Comment: In that case, since you want to avoid adding duplicate objects to the dataLayer based on the event property, your current approach using Array.prototype.some() is still optimal.

Answer (score 1):

What you did already is a good way to do it. You can also use `.every()` and check for `!== 'some_label'`.

If you have a lot of data you can use a map or set to be more efficient when it comes to lookup time. But this only makes sense when you have multiple lookups and a large array size.

```js
// build set with set and events
const set = window.dataLayer.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc.add(el.event);
    return acc;
}, new Set())


// check if the set includes the label
if (!set.includes('some_label')) {
    gtm.push(someTrackingObject);
}
```

#### Update

Search for the element. `.find` exits on the first match so you don't have to check every element in the array.

```js
// check if the set includes the label
if (window.dataLayer.find(el => el.event === 'some_label') === undefined) {
    gtm.push(someTrackingObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a small array (around 20 elements), so the efficiency is not crucial. I think I'll stick with `every` or `some`.